# How to plot a function of an imported data in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

If I have a file of several data points. How can I plot a function of them? For example, suppose I have a file of to columns `x` and `y` and I want to plot `sin(y)` as a function of `1/x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot "-" u (1/$1):(sin($2)) w l
    2.00000    0.16104
    3.00000    0.15604
    4.00000    0.40055
    5.00000    0.09972
    e
```

Or when not using data files make use of the `parametric` mode, which is described [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-14400034.4)

#### EDIT

With this data file `Data.csv`:

```
 0.00000    0.33371
 1.00000    0.13034
 2.00000    0.16104
 3.00000    0.15604
 4.00000    0.40055
 5.00000    0.09972
 6.00000    0.25204
 7.00000   -0.34172
 8.00000   -0.04733
 9.00000   -0.27211
10.00000    0.10229
11.00000   -0.30608
12.00000    0.11006
13.00000   -0.44390
14.00000   -0.16963
15.00000    0.03208
16.00000    0.32431
17.00000    0.15424
18.00000    0.16468
19.00000    0.24410
20.00000    0.34961
```

I can run this script:

```
f(x) = kappa*x**2

fit f(x) "Data.csv" u (log($1)):(sin($2)) via kappa
plot "Data.csv" u 1:(sin($2)), f(x) w l
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image: Plot of the above script and data file]

Granted, the fitting does not make any sense at all^^.

Are you maybe missing some brackets in your fit?!

Comment: Is there a reason why it won't work with log? I try ``fit g(x) 'out.dat' using log($1):log($2)`` via kappa. I don't want to use the logscale option

Comment: @Yotam What is the error message. Fitting data in this form works fine on my machine.

Comment: Yes, I am missing the bracket. I have written ``log($1)`` while I needed to write ``(log($1))``