# Performing math operations on loaded data with GNUplot

Tags: python, bash, gnuplot

I'm using Linux with gnuplot and looking to load a simple two-column data file and plot/save it from a some python code.

I've had no issues following the tutorials and examples with the exception that now I want to perform a mathematical operation on one of the columns, e.g. take the `log10()` of the column so that I'm plotting (for example) `(x, log10(y))` where `x` and `y` are the two columns in the data file.

This is the perfect link showing how to do it:

[How to plot a function of an imported data in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938703/how-to-plot-a-function-of-an-imported-data-in-gnuplot)

The problem is that I want to run a bash script of gnuplot using `gnuplot -e ......`, since I'm running it from Python, and it immediately removes the `$` signs from my script and it doesn't work. If I choose not to transform the data (leave it as is) it runs fine, so all other syntax is okay.

Truth be told, I don't know what the `$` sign is trying to convey and I'm thinking it has something to do with my operating system or something else and not strictly gnuplot. Any insight here would be great.

Comment: Please add to your question your python code and the gnuplot script you are trying to execute.

Comment: I'm kicking myself for not bringing my code with me - I can post it tomorrow. FWIW, it's literally the same as the link shown - the either gnuplot or my OS removes the $ sign since it spits out the script minus the $ symbols. In the meantime, what is the significance of the $ sign in the link I provided above? Thanks.

Comment: Why are `$` signs removed? Do you remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` sign so that the shell does not try to perform variable substitution. You do that by adding backslash right before:

```
gnuplot -e "plot 'filename.dat' using 1:(log10(\$2))"
```

should work.

Comment: This makes sense - I'll try it tomorrow morning and report back - thanks!

Comment: Or, to avoid escaping at all: `using 1:(log10(column(2))`

Comment: Both the escape character / and using column() works - thanks everyone!